# Tower of Hanoi, stop sliding

Tags: java, recursion, towers-of-hanoi

I developed a solution for the Tower of Hanoi problem:

```
public static void bewege(int h, char quelle, char ablage, char ziel) {  
  if(h > 0){
     bewege(h - 1, quelle, ziel, ablage);
     System.out.println("Move "+ h +" from " + quelle + " to " + ziel);
     bewege(h - 1, ablage, quelle, ziel);
 }
}
```

It works fine. Now i want to limit the number of slides and throw an exception if a certain limit is reached. I tried it with a counter but it does not work:

```
class HanoiNK{

 public static void main(String args[]){
   Integer n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
   Integer k = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

   try{
    bewege(k, n, 'A', 'B', 'C');
   }catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
   }
 }

 public static void bewege(int c, int h, char quelle, char ablage, char ziel) 
    throws Exception{  
  if(h > 0){
   if(c != 0){
   bewege(c, h - 1, quelle, ziel, ablage);
   c--;
   System.out.println("Move "+ h +" from " + quelle + " to " + ziel);
   bewege(c, h - 1, ablage, quelle, ziel);
   c--;
   }else{ 
    throw new Exception("stop sliding");
   }
  }
 }
}
```

The exception is never thrown. Any ideas?

**UPDATE: result is 6 slides but it should be 5** http://ideone.com/lm084

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On-topic:

<s>It looks to me as though `counter` is not defined anywhere, and so that shouldn't compile.</s>

Now that you've edited your question to fix the above, the exception will be thrown if your first argument is greater than your second argument, e.g.:

```
java HanoiNK 5 3
```

The exception will occur when `c == 0` and `h == 1`, in that case.

---

**Off-topic**: These lines:

```
Integer n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
Integer k = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
```

should be

```
int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
int k = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
```

...since `parseInt` returns `int` (not `Integer`) and the function you're passing them into accepts `int` (not `Integer`). Auto-boxing probably lets you get away with it, but it's unnecessary.

Comment: when parameters are 4 5 it prints 6 instead of 5 slides, something is wrong

Comment: @ArtWorkAD: Your question originally was, why is the exception never thrown? The answer is: It **is** thrown. I'm afraid I don't know the Tower of Hanoi problem well enough to tell you why your code isn't stopping when you want it to. Good luck with it.

Answer (score 1):

I think `counter == c`? Therefore try too move `c--;` above your `bewege(c, h - 1, ablage, quelle, ziel);` and it should work, so it looks like this:

```
 public static void bewege(int c, int h, char quelle, char ablage, char ziel) 
throws Exception{       
    if(h > 0){
        if(c != 0){
        c--;
        bewege(c, h - 1, quelle, ziel, ablage);
        System.out.println("Move "+ h +" from " + quelle + " to " + ziel);
        c--;
        bewege(c, h - 1, ablage, quelle, ziel);
        }else{  
            throw new Exception("stop sliding");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where the `counter` variable is declared (doesn't seem to be here), but you're not decrementing it anywhere, so it's value will never change.