# Count recursion steps in java

Tags: java, exception, recursion

I want to count the number of recursion steps and stop the recursion when a certain limit is reached.

Actually I am dealing with the Tower of Hanoi problem and I want to limit the number of slides that are performed to solve the problem. Here is my solution:

```
class HanoiNK{

    public static void main(String args[]){

            int n = 4;
            int k = 5;

            try{
                slide(k, n, 'A', 'B', 'C');
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }
    }

    public static void slide(int counter, int height, char source,
                              char buffer, char destination) throws Exception{      
        if(counter > 0){
            if(height == 1){                                
                System.out.println("move "+ height +" from " +
                                                source + " to " + destination);
            }else{  
                counter--;
                slide(counter, height - 1, source, destination, buffer);    
                System.out.println("move "+ hoehe +" from " +
                                                source + " to " + destination);
                counter--;
                slide(counter, height - 1, buffer, source, destination);    
            }
        }else{
            throw new Exception("stop here");
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is the live example:** http://ideone.com/xeN4x

My problem is that I get

```
move 1 from A to B
move 2 from A to C
move 1 from B to C
move 3 from A to B
move 1 from C to A
move 2 from C to B
java.lang.Exception: stop
```

as output. But 5 and not 6 slides should be performed. Any ideas?

Comment: do you want to limit the recursion depth (=n) or the number of moves (=2^n-1)?

Comment: actually I am not sure about the context of depth and moves but I want to limit the moves!

Comment: exceptions in Java (and especially checked exceptions, but that is another topic) are way overused in Java.  Here you're using an exception as a glorified GOTO statement: this is terribly bad.  At the same time, it's a great example as to how exceptions can be misused so I kinda like your question ;)

Comment: re-word and re-post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570685/tower-of-hanoi-stop-sliding

Comment: no, that question was on the non thrown exception problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to count the number of moves and **not** the recursion depth, you need to store the number of moves that were made in each step. Something like this:

```
    public static int slide(int counter, int hoehe, char quelle,                           char ablage, char ziel)
throws Exception{         
    if (hoehe == 1) {          
        System.out.println("move "+ hoehe +" from " +                                             
                quelle + " to " + ziel);   
        if (--counter == 0) throw new Exception("hier stoppen"); 
    } else {     
        counter = slide(counter, hoehe - 1, quelle, ziel, ablage);     
        System.out.println("move "+ hoehe +" from " +          
                quelle + " to " + ziel);             
        if (--counter == 0) throw new Exception("hier stoppen"); 
        counter = slide(counter, hoehe - 1, ablage, quelle, ziel);       
    }     
    return counter;
}
```

Then, you obtain the expected result:

```
move 1 from A to B
move 2 from A to C
move 1 from B to C
move 3 from A to B
move 1 from C to A
java.lang.Exception: hier stoppen
```

Comment: why you check the 2nd --counter == 0 exactly at that position and not straight after the else?

Comment: Because right after the `else` you haven't done any moves yet. If the check was there, the code would stop after three moves (in your example with `n=4` and `k=5`) in the base condition (`hoehe == 1`). Therefore you'd never see the two remaining `println`/move in the `else` part.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is you are testing if counter is greater than or equal to **one**, but then decrementing it by **two**.

```
counter--;
// ...
counter--;
```

Here counter can go negative. You need to check for that.

Comment: Want to add that stopping recursion with an exception is questionable.

Comment: Though that's not really the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an sample method that will be recursively get called `counter` times

```
public void callMe(int counter){
      if(counter == 1 ){
             return;
      }else{
             callMe(--counter);
      }

}
```

in your code there are `counter--;` twice so it won't met condition in many case

Answer (score 0):

You have to test for your counter at every decrements like this:

```
public static void slide(int counter, int hoehe, char quelle,
                      char ablage, char ziel) throws Exception{
    if(hoehe == 1){
        System.out.println("move "+ hoehe +" from " +
                                        quelle + " to " + ziel);
    }else{
        if (--counter == 0) throw new Exception("hier stoppen");
        slide(counter, hoehe - 1, quelle, ziel, ablage);
        System.out.println("move "+ hoehe +" from " +
                                        quelle + " to " + ziel);
        if (--counter == 0) throw new Exception("hier stoppen");
        slide(counter, hoehe - 1, ablage, quelle, ziel);
    }
}
```

Comment: that does not work too if you check it on ideone.com; I think there is a difference between recursion step and slide itself. maybe a global counter would solve the problem, I will try that now

Comment: You don't need a global counter if you return the number of moves that were done in each step. Check my solution.